# Source for if $L_A:(\mathbb{R}^n, \left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert_p) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert_q)$ is an isometry, then $p = q$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, normed-spaces

Let and $n\geq 3$ be a natural number and $p,q\in [1,\infty]$.

For any $n\times n$ square matrix $A$, let $L_A:(\mathbb{R}^n, \left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert_p) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \left\Vert \cdot \right\Vert_q)$ be defined by $L_A(z) = Az$, that is, $L_A$ is the pre-matrix multiplication operator.

I think the following fact is well-known.

> If $L_A$ is an isometry, then $p = q$.

I am looking for a research paper or book that cites the result above.
However, I am not able to get any.

Comment: See the paper http://matematicas.unex.es/~fcabello/files/printable/01.pdf and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620460/mathbbrn-cdot-p-is-isometrically-isomorphic-to-mathbbrn

Comment: @RobertZ Nice reference! Maybe you can post it as an answer so that I can close this question?

Comment: I think that your question is a duplicate. It is not fair to give an answer which is simply a reference to an already existing question.